# What is the best way to persist user sessions in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I'm using a standalone Keycloak server. I have created one realm and a user inside that realm. When I log in the user and restart keycloak server, the session gets lost.

I am aware that keycloak saves user sessions data in Infinispan. But is there any way I can save/persist this user session data?

Or shall I create multiple nodes cluster and replicate the keycloak session data?

Please suggest what's best.

Comment: Configure persistent cache store - https://infinispan.org/cache-store-implementations e.g. to the file/db/...

Comment: So, are you saying that I need to set up a separate infinispan and then use persistence config with that ??

Comment: Depends on you concrete scenario. Does it need to survive a full clsuter restart? Otherwise you may simply set up a cluster and replicate session state to multiple owning nodes.

Answer (score 4):

We also have this problem.

So far I think there are 2 solutions, neither of them is perfect:

## 1. Keep sessions in infinispan

You can use [external infinispan instance as described in the docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#crossdc-mode). This is cumbersome because you need to keep an external infinispan instance.

If you don't want to use an external infinispan instance, you can set `CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT` in the docker image >=2. This will rebalance the cache between nodes and will make sure that an entry is saved in at lease `CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT` nodes. If you have many sessions (>1Million) you will run out of memory and the startup time will increase substantially because the cache needs to be rebalanced at each deploy.

Another issue is that you would loose the sessions when updating the infinispan instance.

## 2. Use offline sessions

Offline sessions are kept in the  db and some of them are kept in the offline_sessions_cache. You can limit the number of offline sessions keycloak keeps in memory and stop preloading offline session for faster startup as described [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-keycloak-start-up-faster-when-there-are-a-lot-of-offline-sessions-78ee49a907cb).

This also has drawbacks:

- SSO will not work after the server is restarted
- You cannot change any offline session notes

I think there are some PRs in keycloak to have a persistent session store build in so please keep an eye on the [progress](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/9666) on the [keycloak Github page](https://github.com/orgs/keycloak/projects/9)

Comment: What about to configure embedded infinispan to save data into DB, e.g. https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-x-persisting-infinispan-to-jdbc-store/6492 ?

Comment: @JanGaraj You can see more about this here: https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-dev/c/sOBzG76f2FE

Note that you need to persist both userSessions and clientSessions. I also think this has issues when updating the embedded infinispan version so we did not follow with this path.